# Haskell - Using previously computed values in next function calls in a sequence

Tags: list, function, parsing, haskell, evaluation

I'm trying to make a function for syntax tree arithmetic operations and thus far I'm almost where I want it to be. In the code I attach you can see my current function definitions. `eval` is the function that decides what to do with each operation and `foldAndPropagateConstants` is the main function. `parse` is a simple parser that takes a `String` of a mathematical expression and returns the equivalent tree. e.g.

```
ghci> parse "3+x"
BinaryOperation Plus (Leaf (Constant 3)) (Leaf (Variable "x"))
```

The issue I'm facing is how to have the evaluated values to be used in subsequent operations. For example, this operation should work as follows:

```
ghci> foldAndPropagateConstants [("x", parse "1+2+3"), ("y", parse "5*x + 7")]
[("x",Leaf (Constant 6)),("y",Leaf (Constant 37))]
```

Notice that the function should use the value that `"x"` got, when calculating the value for `"y"`. Thing is, I can't seem to find a way to use `"x"`'s value in my `eval` function.

```
--foldAndPropagateConstants :: [(String, Exprv)] -> [(String, ExprV)]

eval :: ExprV -> Int
eval (Leaf (Variable n)) = --this part is what's missing
eval (Leaf (Constant n)) = n
eval (BinaryOperation Plus expr1 expr2) = eval expr1 + eval expr2
eval (BinaryOperation Times expr1 expr2) = eval expr1 * eval expr2
eval (UnaryOperation Minus expr1) = -1 * eval expr1

foldAndPropagateConstants (x:xs) = [(fst x, parse (show (eval(snd x)))) ] : foldAndPropagateConstants xs
foldAndPropagateConstants _ = []
```

Comment: Usually this is done by adding an "environment" parameter to `eval` which stores the values of all variables, as a `Data.Map` or similar.

Comment: Probably should've pointed out that I'm rather new to Haskell. Not sure how that would be done. @luqui

Comment: Adding a parameter to your function's type and definition is something you can learn by reading any number of resources.

Comment: As @luqui said, the best is to use an environment such as as List or a Map, in which you store variables and their values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit: I seem to have answered only this part of the question:*

> I can't seem to find a way to use "x" value in my eval function.

Since your question does not include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), here is a simplified version of what you seem to be doing (that doesn't contain variables) that both contains the `data` definition and the `eval` function:

```hs
module Eval where

data Expr
  = Constant Int
  | UnOp UnaryOperation Expr
  | BinOp BinaryOperation Expr Expr
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data UnaryOperation
  = UnaryMinus
  | UnaryFactorial
  | UnaryAbsolute
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data BinaryOperation
  = Plus
  | Minus
  | Times
  | Divide
  deriving (Eq, Show)

eval :: Expr -> Int
eval (Constant n) = n
eval (UnOp UnaryMinus e) = negate (eval e)
eval (UnOp UnaryFactorial e) = product [1..eval e]
eval (UnOp UnaryAbsolute e) = abs (eval e)
eval (BinOp bop e1 e2) = evalBinOp bop (eval e1) (eval e2)

evalBinOp :: BinaryOperation -> Int -> Int -> Int
evalBinOp Plus = (+)
evalBinOp Minus = (-)
evalBinOp Times = (*)
evalBinOp Divide = div
```

Extending this evaluator with another constructor in `data Expr`, and extending the `eval` function with an "environment" as luqui suggests, which in this case is a list of name-value pairs:

```hs
data Expr
  = Constant Int
  | Variable String
  | UnOp UnaryOperation Expr
  | BinOp BinaryOperation Expr Expr
  deriving (Eq, Show)

-- ...

eval :: Expr -> [(String, Int)] -> Int
eval (Constant n) _env = n
eval (Variable s) env = lookup' s env
eval (UnOp UnaryMinus e) env = negate (eval e env)
eval (UnOp UnaryFactorial e) env = product [1..eval e env]
eval (UnOp UnaryAbsolute e) env = abs (eval e env)
eval (BinOp bop e1 e2) env = evalBinOp bop (eval e1 env) (eval e2 env)

-- ...

lookup' :: String -> [(String, Int)] -> Int
lookup' s [] = error ("Could not find variable " ++ s)
lookup' s ((t,n):env)
  | s == t = n
  | otherwise = lookup' s env
```

It seems to me that the most urgent improvement to this evaluator is better error handling using error-aware return types. I made the `lookup'` helper function because the standard library function [`Data.List.lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup) uses the safer `Maybe` return type which would encourage the rewrite I'm suggesting:

```hs
eval :: Expr -> [(String, Int)] -> Maybe Int
eval (Constant n) _env = pure n
eval (Variable s) env = lookup s env
eval (UnOp UnaryMinus e) env =
  case eval e env of
    Just n -> pure (negate n)
    Nothing -> Nothing
eval (UnOp UnaryFactorial e) env =
  eval e env >>= \n ->
  pure (product [1..n])
eval (UnOp UnaryAbsolute e) env =
  abs <$> eval e env
eval (BinOp bop e1 e2) env = do
  n1 <- eval e1 env
  n2 <- eval e2 env
  pure (evalBinOp bop n1 n2)
```

I've used a different style in each function body, but they're all variations of a similar theme: case-of uses explicit pattern matching, which gets tedious. (Imagine doing the `eval (BinOp ...)` body using case-of.) Explicit use of the `>>=` operator is... I suppose some people like it, but `do` notation looks prettier. The `<$>` [applicative style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104446/how-do-you-use-control-applicative-to-write-cleaner-haskell) is the neatest of them all in this case, I think.

What you could do next is make the `env` implicit by using the `Reader` monad: It is a bit messy that only one function body in `eval` actually uses it, and all the others either throw it away or pass it along.

Comment: Neat. I haven't understood it fully yet, but may I ask why you use evalBinOp? is it like an added functionality?

Comment: So, I think I understand your solution thus far, which I must say is pretty neat. One confusion I'm facing is how to pass the second variable in the definition of `foldAndPorpagateConstants` function.
The definition I have:
`foldAndPropagateConstants (x:xs) = [(fst x, parse (show (eval(snd x)))) ] : foldAndPropagateConstants xs`
Gives me an error which I think is because eval has too few arguments after modifying it to have an "environment" variable.

Comment: @MoodMojo: The `evalBinOp` is just to avoid four cases directly in `eval` just as there are three cases for `UnOp`. It is only a matter of convenience. The question you are asking about `foldAnd...` is outside the scope of this answer. Asking follow-up questions that warrant long answers in comments is not going to work on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sure. Your answer does cover what you said it does so thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is for

```
foldAndPropagateConstants [("x", parse "1+2+3"), ("y", parse "5*x + 7"), ("z", parse "x+y-1")]
```

to be equivalent to

```
 =  let s0 = []

        r1 = parse' "1+2+3" s0
        -- r1 = Leaf (Constant 6)
        s1 = [("x",6)]

        r2 = parse' "5*x + 7" s1 
        -- r2 = Leaf (Constant 37)
        s2 = [("x",6),("y",37)]

        r3 = parse' "x+y-1" s2 
        -- r3 = Leaf (Constant 42)
        s3 = [("x",6),("y",37),("z",42)]
    in
       [r1,r2,r3]
```

`parse'` is like `parse`, but it can also consult a store of values known so far which it receives as its second argument.

The above is easier encoded with functions if restructured as

```
 =  let s0 = []

        (s1, r1) = parse'' "1+2+3" s0
        -- r1 = Leaf (Constant 6)
        -- s1 = [("x",6)]

        (s2, r2) = parse'' "5*x + 7" s1 
        -- r2 = Leaf (Constant 37)
        -- s2 = [("x",6),("y",37)]

        (s3, r3) = parse'' "x+y-1" s2 
        -- r3 = Leaf (Constant 42)
        -- s3 = [("x",6),("y",37),("z",42)]
    in
       snd (s3, [r1,r2,r3])
```

Incidentally this pattern of *state-passing computations* is known as State Monad, but that's a matter for another day.

The above fits the *recursion* pattern when expressed as

```
foldAndPropagateConstants [("x", parse "1+2+3"), ("y", parse "5*x + 7"), ("z", parse "x+y-1")] = 
    snd $ foldAndPropagateConstants' 
            [("x", parse "1+2+3"), ("y", parse "5*x + 7"), ("z", parse "x+y-1")] 
            []

foldAndPropagateConstants' [("x", parse "1+2+3"), ("y", parse "5*x + 7"), ("z", parse "x+y-1")] s0 =
    let 
        (s1, r1) = parse'' "1+2+3" s0
        (sn, rs) = foldAndPropagateConstants' [("y", parse "5*x + 7"), ("z", parse "x+y-1")] s1 
    in
       (sn, r1 : rs)

-- and

foldAndPropagateConstants' [] s0 = (s0, [])
```

And now, *[**Generalize!**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51280660/849891) (by replacing an example value with a symbolic one).*

Comment: But how will it actually calculate the value of the expression? You don't seem to use a helper function for that purpose in your solution like `eval` so I'm not sure how you got this to work.

Comment: I didn't go into the specifics here. Just concerned myself with the general structure of the code, as you asked how can the previously computed values be used in the subsequent computations (that's how I interpreted your question).

Comment: so this answer is an expansion of [luqui's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60901892/haskell-using-previously-computed-values-in-next-function-calls-in-a-sequence/60908414?noredirect=1#comment107750278_60901892).

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks once again, Will. :)

Comment: I'll try to use what you guys explained, but to ensure I understood correctly, you are making another function, namely `foldAndPropagateConstants'` to keep the environment variable as luqui suggested, right? and the same with `parse'`

Comment: something like that. and parse', (and parse'') need to be augmented accordingly to fit its new use.